# how apply function to Dropdown?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to use function ToggleDropDown()  for dropdown asp tag:::?
I want to enter text In between  All  tag
when user select from dropdown

```
function ToggleDropDown(targetId, targetSelcteTextId) {
        var e = document.getElementById("" + targetId + "");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        $("#" + targetSelcteTextId + "").text(strUser);
    }
```

my code ..>>

```
<span class="ui-btn-inner">
    <span class="ui-btn-text" id="ddpChannelCatgSELECTED" onchange="ToggleDorpDown('ddpChannelCatg', 'ddpChannelCatgSELECTED')">
      <span>All</span>
    </span>
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-d ui-icon-shadow"></span>
```

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" TabIndex="508" Width="100%" ID="ddpChannelCatg" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#<%= ddpChannelCatg.ClientID %>").change(function(){
        ToggleDorpDown(this.id, 'ddpChannelCatgSELECTED');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function ToggleDropDown(targetId, targetSelcteTextId) {
    $('#' + targetSelcteTextId).text($('#' + targetId).find('option:selected').html());
};
```